# Show the latest post as Rails root page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple Rails blogging app and I currently have a welcome page set as my apps "home" page in my routes file.

```
  root 'welcome#show'
```

I also have garden variety `show` and `index` methods in my `PostsController`:

```
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @posts = Post.all.order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page]).per_page(1)
  end
```

What I really want to do is set my `root/home` page to be the `latest/most-recent/highest-id post`.

For example if my last post was `posts/57` this would be the home page.

To clear, I don't just want the content of the last post to appear on the front page... I literally want the latest post to be front page. If id 57 was the last post the url would read "post/57".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using `redirect_to`

In **app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb**:

```
def show
  redirect_to post_path(Post.last) and return
end
```

This will redirect the user to the latest post page.  Note that this will result in two requests to the web server: the first being *welcome#show* and the second being *posts#show*.

### Using Partials

[Layouts and Rendering - Using Partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials).

Create **app/views/posts/_post.html.erb** which should contain HTML for a Post.  It should be similar to **app/views/posts/show.html.erb** but notice it uses `post` instead of `@post`:

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= post.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Body:</strong>
  <%= post.body %>
</p>
```

Then somewhere in **app/views/welcome/show.html.erb**:

```
<%= render partial: 'posts/post', locals: { post: Post.last } %>
```

Comment: This is super helpful and achieves the result of getting the content of the last post anywhere I like, but it's not really what I'm after. I literally want the latest post to be front page. If id 57 was the last post the url would read "post/57".

Comment: @Dennis How about a simple redirect to your latest post?  Check my edit above.

Comment: Bingo. Just what I was looking for. The partial answer is also handy for others who have a similar question. I also like this solution because it give me simple way to change it back to my Welcome page if I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Override `root_path` and `root_url` in your `ApplicationController`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def root_path
    latest_post = Post.order("id DESC").first
    post_path(latest_post)
  end

  def root_url
    latest_post = Post.order("id DESC").first
    post_url(latest_post)
  end
end
```

This will set the root as post path if the post exists, otherwise it will be set to `welcome#show`

Comment: Just tried it and simply doesn't work. Plus, I know I'll have a post -- if I don't, I have bigger issues -- so is the if statement over-engineering?

Comment: Yeah, now that you say the post will always be present, if is not needed. Also it would really help if you post what you see with this code instead of saying `simply doesn't work`

Comment: I still get 'welcome#show' as the home page and if I remove it from routes.rb, I get the rails welcome page.